# Price Scraping: Element not visible in html

Tags: python, html, parsing, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract the price value of in the linked website using beautfulsoup in python.  I am able to see the  where the price is when I use 'Inspect Element', but I do not see it when using 'View Source'

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get('https://www.rolex.com/en-us/watches/air-king/m126900-0001.html')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
s = soup.find('span', "class=sc-fznKkj sc-fzqNJr sc-qWdEB emvJfj")
```

When I run this code the object s is empty rather than including the price.

Comment: I don't see any price value in the given website. Can you help? Also if you have to interact  (by clicking or otherwise) with the website to display the price on the website, Selenium is  required for the job.

Comment: The price is available at the left corner of the page, but it gets dynamically created based on your local currency of the country you live in, which is why BS or using view source cannot show you the price. Like @Bunny said, Selenium would be a better option for this.

Answer (score 0):

The price data loads from a [json file](https://www.rolex.com/content/api/rolex/model-price.US.m126900-0001.en_us.json). You can see this by loading up Dev Tools and searching for the price (`7,400` for me) and seeing what request loaded the price.

The code to get the price is simple :)

```
response = requests.get("https://www.rolex.com/content/api/rolex/model-price.US.m126900-0001.en_us.json").json()
price = response['formattedPrice'] # $7,400
```

Comment: Thanks! This works.  How were you able to tell that price was loading from json file here?

Comment: And how did you know the url of the json?

Comment: The price has to come from somewhere. If it's not in the initial page load, it is loaded from a different request. As i said in my answer, load up the Dev Tools, reload the page, and search for "7,400" and you'll see the request that loaded in the price.